# display dd on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `dl` in my page that contain multiple `dt` and `dd`.I just want to hide all `dd` except one when clicked on 'dt'. Basically i want to build horizontal nav bar.

this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/9kt6pdx5/2/)

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Tabs 01</dt>
    <dd style="display:block;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 01 clicked</p>
    </dd>
    <dt>tab 02</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 02 clicked</p>
    </dd>
    <dt>tab 03</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 03 clicked</p>
     </dd>
     <span style="left: 222px; top: 28px; display: block;"></span>
</dl>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dl-horizontal dt').click(function(){

            $('.dl-horizontal dt').removeClass('unactive')
            $(this).next().toggleClass('active');     

        });

});
```

so when i clicked on tab that tab content will shown.How can i do this using jquery

Comment: how can i display clicked dt contents

Comment: Note: Your HTML has attribute-based styles, which will always take precedence over class-based styles in CSS. I have also noted this as the actual cause of your code not working at all. You do not need classes at all to get the result you want (answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/9kt6pdx5/14/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tabs">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Tabs 01</dt>
            <dd>
                <p>Content that is shown when tab 01 clicked</p>
            </dd>
            <dt>tab 02</dt>
            <dd>
                <p>Content that is shown when tab 02 clicked</p>
            </dd>
            <dt>tab 03</dt>
            <dd>
                <p>Content that is shown when tab 03 clicked</p>
             </dd>
             <span style="left: 222px; top: 28px; display: block;"></span></dl>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $dts = $('.dl-horizontal dt');
        $('.dl-horizontal').on('click', 'dt', function(){
             $dts.removeClass('active');
             $(this).addClass('active');


        });

    });

dd {
  display: none;
}
dt.active + dd{
  display : block;  
}
```

By clicking on `dt` class `active` will be added to the element. When class is added `display: block` will be applied to next `dd` because of CSS adjacent sibling selector, i.e. `dt.active + dd`

Comment: Although it "works", I do see how you alone got an up-vote for this *without an explanation of what you did* (e.g. using a CSS *adjacent sibling* selector). Also a delegated event handler is not necessary here and you did not scope your `$dts` variable.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, my bad for not scoping $dts, used to work with coffeescript where scoping done automatically. also i missed semicolon there. About event delegating, i do not see reason for not using it there. There are several elements that listen click event, so delegating will decrease overhead for monitoring them, even if improvement is very little in this situation.

Comment: As you say, the benefit of a delegated event in this case is zero, but you still need to edit your question to explain *what you did* as that CSS `+` may not be obvious to others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<span class='test'>
    <dt>Tabs 01</dt>
    <dd style="display:block;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 01 clicked</p>
    </dd>
</span>
<span class='test'>
    <dt>tab 02</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 02 clicked</p>
    </dd>
</span>
<span class='test'>
    <dt>tab 03</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 03 clicked</p>
     </dd>
</span>
     <span style="left: 222px; top: 28px; display: block;"></span>
</dl>

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('dt').click(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $show_dd = $this.closest('.test').find('dd');
            $('.test dd').hide();
            $show_dd.show();

        });
    });
```

required jquery

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for this as it does not appear to work?

Comment: That new JSFiddle does work, but is not the same code you posted. You may want to update your answer

Answer (score 0):

One class is enought. Take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/9kt6pdx5/3/

```
$('.dl-horizontal dt').click(function(){

    $(this).next().toggleClass('unactive');   

});
```

Comment: Good use of toggle, and one class is appropriate (even if it is still misspelt), although the code implies the "other" tabs should close when you open one.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate **only** the elements that need to be manipulated by adding the correct classes or pseudo selectors to the selector. I have added `.active` to the first `dd` because it is the active dd when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dl-horizontal dt').click(function(){

            $('dd.active:visible').hide().removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('dd').show().addClass( 'active' );

        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Tabs 01</dt>
    <dd style="display:block;" class="active">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 01 clicked</p>
    </dd>
    <dt>tab 02</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 02 clicked</p>
    </dd>
    <dt>tab 03</dt>
    <dd style="display:none;">
        <p>Content that is shown when tab 03 clicked</p>
     </dd>
     <span style="left: 222px; top: 28px; display: block;"></span>
</dl>
```

Comment: Selecting the second element leaves the first open (no toggle open/closed).

Comment: Correct, thanks! Adding `.active` to the first `dd` in the markup resolves that. @TrueBlueAussie?

Answer (score 0):

You may try addClass and removeClass on click event

```
$(function(){
   //Event listener for <dt>
   $('dt').on('click',function({  
        //reset the inactive class to <dd>
        $('dd').addClass('inactive'); 
        //remove the inactive class and add active class 
        $(this).next('dd').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');//method chaining           
   });    
});
```

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kt6pdx5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one open at a time, with no toggle closed, you don't even need classes. Just slide up "the others" (using `not`) and slide down the selection (or `hide()`/`show()` if you prefer a more jarring experience):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9kt6pdx5/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dl-horizontal dt').click(function () {
        var $dd = $(this).next('dd');
        $('.dl-horizontal dd').not($dd).slideUp();
        $dd.slideDown();
    });
});
```

**notes:**

- Your original example has element `style=` attributes, which will always override class CSS styles you added. That is why it did not work.